# Difference of speed if SQL Server is on one server and website is on another, rather than both on same server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005

We have db and website on same server. I would like to know that what would be the pros and cons of dedicated server for db (SQL Server 2005) and for website (webserver is IIS).

Same db is also connected with a windows application. **Will there be any difference in speed by transferring db to a dedicated server?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have web and database servers on different machines is both a security and performance enhancements.
[Stackoverflow similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659970/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-have-the-database-and-web-server-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: Thanks @lg- Can you give me reference of any article, it will be great help.

Comment: I add a link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Running SQL Server on a dedicated server is always recommended. In a shared server where you have SQL Server and other applications running, there will always be contention for the resources.

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep- Can you give me reference of any article, it will be great help.